# emit same named events from multiple modules - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my **angularjs** application i have several modules,

what i'm trying to achieve is identify the loaded modules to the application.
for this i am using **$emit** and **$on** in **angularjs**.

from configurations handling module i listen to the configs send from other modules from run function of configuration module

```
    $rootScope.$on('MOD_CONFIG',function(event,data){
        console.log('got config'+data.name);
    });
```

from other modules run methods i send each modules config by using

```
    $rootScope.$emit('MOD_CONFIG',{name : "admin_module"});

    $rootScope.$emit('MOD_CONFIG',{name : "chart_module"});
```

but the problem i'm facing here is only one module is detected in this manner.

for example, **admin_module** is logged correctly to the console but all the others fails, when i comment the **admin_module** then i can see that the **chart_module** is working fine.

as i can understand only one $emit from the given name is detected?

is this the real scenario happening?  how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: have you tried to use $broadcast instead of $emit?

Comment: hi , i have tried out the same scenario using $broadcast, result is the same.

Comment: try to emit it from other controller, just to test and let me know your inputs

Comment: @FelipeKM : i think $broadcast is working, after posting in to the thread i have moved my module configurations to a constant **$provide.constant('MOD_CONFIG',{ name : 'admin_module' });**  then i saw your reply and tried the $broadcast , after working for some times, i just went through the DOM via firebug and found that **$inject ["MOD_CONFIG", "$rootScope"]** is on module definition in DOM, this means that i am re assigning the MOD_CONFIG in $rootScope it leads to 2 hits to $on, with one name. :)